# sharpen image quality with PHP gd library

Tags: php, gd

not sure where but I came across as image hosting site that allows you to upload your image in a large format or to sharpen it.

I personally do not recall or know of any functions of GD library to sharpen image which might just be a different word for quality being up-ed.

If some one knows of a function to sharpen images please tell me since personally I am not aware of such functions neither in Image Magic and/or GD Library.

- Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `imageconvolution()` with a matrix that corresponds to a sharpen filter. Details in this comment on the PHP site: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php#56144

Comment: A so there was an image sharpening function, but personally never used imageconvolution() so would not know much about it

Comment: That's what most sharpen/unsharpen filters are in image editors - a convolution function with a matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [imageconvolution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php) in GD with a sharpen mask. From [http://adamhopkinson.co.uk/blog/2010/08/26/sharpen-an-image-using-php-and-gd/](https://web.archive.org/web/20191130192906/http://adamhopkinson.co.uk/blog/2010/08/26/sharpen-an-image-using-php-and-gd/):

> PHP and GD can sharpen images by providing a matrix to `imageconvolution`:
>
> ```php
> // create the image resource from a file
> $i = imagecreatefromjpeg('otter.jpg');
>
> // define the sharpen matrix
> $sharpen = array(
>   array(0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
>   array(-1.0, 5.0, -1.0),
>   array(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
> );
>
> // calculate the sharpen divisor
> $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $sharpen));
>
> // apply the matrix
> imageconvolution($i, $sharpen, $divisor, 0);
>
> // output the image
> header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
> imagejpeg($i);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but [this](http://redskiesatnight.com/2005/04/06/sharpening-using-image-magick/) looks like what you're looking for, as far as ImageMagick goes.

Answer (score 0):

In GD library of php having a file with path

```
lib/PHPImageWorkshop/Core/ImageWorkshopLayer.php
```

Please go to save public function and you can change the imageQuality upto 100.
make sure which type of image you want to create. 
Hope this will help you.